# Unable to Insert data into database in jsf Application

Tags: mysql, jsf, jdbc, jsf-2

I am trying to insert data into a database named mtdb , table userDB
I am writing my web app in JSF, I am able to render the primeface elements included in my code and when I click submit it is not inserting anything into the database can you please help me out

my XHTML page is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Simple Web App</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel>Name:</p:outputLabel> <p:inputText id="nmn" value="#{sgbean.nmn}" />
    <p:outputLabel>Password:</p:outputLabel> <p:inputText id="pwd" value="#{sgbean.pwd}" />
    <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Submit" type="Submit" action="sgbean.add" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Managed Bean Code:

```
package jsfappTest;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@ManagedBean(name="sgbean")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanGs {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = null; 
    int i=0;
    private String nmn;
    private String pwd;
    private String msg;
    
    public String getNmn() {
        return nmn;
    }
    public void setNmn(String nmn) {
        this.nmn = nmn;
    }
    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }
    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }
    
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;   }
                            
    public void add(){

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mtdb", "root", " ");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO userDB(name,pwd) VALUES(?,?)";
                        ps= con.prepareStatement(sql); 
                        ps.setString(1, nmn);
                        ps.setString(2, pwd);
                        i = ps.executeUpdate();
                        System.out.println("Data Added Successfully");
                }

        catch(Exception e)
                {
                        System.out.println(e); 
                }
        finally
        {
        try
        {
        con.close();
        ps.close();
        }
                    
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        
   }
}
```

Comment: Any exception? try ajax="false" with your command button

Comment: I tried doing that but it dosen't work out, the page is refreshing after adding the code but it is not adding any data into the database , it is not even yielding an error

Comment: Is there a transaction? Or commit somewhere? Most likely not. In that case it is totally jsf/primefaces unrelate but jdbc

Comment: Do i need to change the statement of jdbc ?

Comment: Assuming the data is submitted to the fields and the method is called: If there is no autocommit, I think you better read some jdbc tutorial about commits and transactions...

Comment: Yeah that works!!, i included "throw new Faces Exception(e);" in the catch block to show the exception and it finally worked, i also included the "mySQl-connector-jar"  file and made some changes to the database statement finally it inserted values into the database  - Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my managedBean "try" and "catch" blocks shown in the above to identify the error

```
 try
            {
                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mtdb", "root", "");
                     con.setAutoCommit(false);

                     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                     String sql = "INSERT INTO userdb(name,pwd) VALUES('"+nmn+"','"+pwd+"')";

                     stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                     con.commit();


            }
```

Catch block is updated as

```
catch(Exception e)
            {
                   throw new FacesException(e);
            }
```

Then i included the "mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" file under lib folder and it worked absolutely fine Thanks for all the help finally i am able to figure it out using the hints provided

Comment: First, I'd certainly try a newer mysql-connector. Secondly, you now explicitly set the autocommit to false and use an explicit commit. Did you check if autocommit was false to begin with (since by default it is true in mysql/jdbc)? Or were there exceptions?

Comment: If we begin with autocommit=true which is default it is not possible to commit it caused me an error "javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true"  but when i removed con.setAutoCommit(false); and con.commit(), it works normally as if it worked with the both the statements included.

Comment: Correct, with autocommit=true you should not need to do a manual commit so getting an error then is expected... But was autocommit true (not set from java or whatever, maybe even on the database level) when you first posted your issue? (do a print of `con.getAutoCommit()` before you set it in your code and check if it is true or false)

Comment: It should be true by default right i am unaware of the auto commit at that time, the main problem  raised is with the connector statement where i accidentally gave my password as " " instead of ""  i am unable to identify that error untill i used " throw new FacesException(e);" , which showed me the root cause for the error and fixed it real quick

Comment: By Default it says "False" , when i submitted the form the value changed to "true"

Comment: Then I'd try to find out why/how it got set to false

Answer (score -1):

the action property on the p:commandbutton should be as action="#{sgbean.add()}

Comment: No, there is no need to do that. Since it the action attribute does not expect a valueexpression by default, the () is not needed

Comment: why -1? @sam_bam you also missed #{ } in your action he taught. He is not talking about () only

Comment: i didn't gave -1, even  i dont have any privileges to give "-1" as my rep is less the required @Sarz